# Pandas ticker to ohlc

Tags: python, pandas

rows is a list of dict from mysql.

rows example

```
[{'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 27, 20), 'tid': 648605515L, 'price': Decimal('1080.04000000'), 'type': 1, 'amount': Decimal('10.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 27, 20), 'tid': 648605549L, 'price': Decimal('1081.55000000'), 'type': 1, 'amount': Decimal('16.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 27, 20), 'tid': 648605547L, 'price': Decimal('1081.33000000'), 'type': 1, 'amount': Decimal('20.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 27, 20), 'tid': 648605545L, 'price': Decimal('1081.30000000'), 'type': 1, 'amount': Decimal('16.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 27, 20), 'tid': 648605543L, 'price': Decimal('1081.29000000'), 'type': 1, 'amount': Decimal('20.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 27, 20), 'tid': 648605541L, 'price': Decimal('1080.46000000'), 'type': 1, 'amount': Decimal('26.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 27, 20), 'tid': 648605517L, 'price': Decimal('1080.04000000'), 'type': 1, 'amount': Decimal('8.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 27, 22), 'tid': 648605601L, 'price': Decimal('1079.69000000'), 'type': -1, 'amount': Decimal('70.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 27, 25), 'tid': 648605686L, 'price': Decimal('1079.72000000'), 'type': -1, 'amount': Decimal('4.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 27, 26), 'tid': 648605765L, 'price': Decimal('1079.45000000'), 'type': 1, 'amount': Decimal('6.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 27, 26), 'tid': 648605753L, 'price': Decimal('1079.60000000'), 'type': -1, 'amount': Decimal('106.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 27, 26), 'tid': 648605751L, 'price': Decimal('1079.60000000'), 'type': -1, 'amount': Decimal('80.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 27, 26), 'tid': 648605749L, 'price': Decimal('1079.67000000'), 'type': -1, 'amount': Decimal('430.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 27, 26), 'tid': 648605747L, 'price': Decimal('1079.70000000'), 'type': -1, 'amount': Decimal('66.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 27, 26), 'tid': 648605745L, 'price': Decimal('1079.74000000'), 'type': -1, 'amount': Decimal('12.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 27, 27), 'tid': 648605785L, 'price': Decimal('1079.45000000'), 'type': 1, 'amount': Decimal('2.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 27, 27), 'tid': 648605774L, 'price': Decimal('1079.45000000'), 'type': 1, 'amount': Decimal('6.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 27, 27), 'tid': 648605771L, 'price': Decimal('1079.45000000'), 'type': 1, 'amount': Decimal('14.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 27, 28), 'tid': 648605827L, 'price': Decimal('1079.45000000'), 'type': 1, 'amount': Decimal('42.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 27, 28), 'tid': 648605842L, 'price': Decimal('1079.45000000'), 'type': 1, 'amount': Decimal('10.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 27, 32), 'tid': 648605973L, 'price': Decimal('1079.45000000'), 'type': 1, 'amount': Decimal('2.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 27, 37), 'tid': 648606114L, 'price': Decimal('1079.44000000'), 'type': 1, 'amount': Decimal('24.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 27, 37), 'tid': 648606116L, 'price': Decimal('1079.45000000'), 'type': 1, 'amount': Decimal('40.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 27, 42), 'tid': 648606258L, 'price': Decimal('1079.45000000'), 'type': 1, 'amount': Decimal('56.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 27, 45), 'tid': 648606345L, 'price': Decimal('1079.46000000'), 'type': -1, 'amount': Decimal('10.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 27, 46), 'tid': 648606392L, 'price': Decimal('1079.69000000'), 'type': 1, 'amount': Decimal('44.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 27, 48), 'tid': 648606418L, 'price': Decimal('1079.60000000'), 'type': -1, 'amount': Decimal('40.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 27, 48), 'tid': 648606420L, 'price': Decimal('1079.46000000'), 'type': -1, 'amount': Decimal('36.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 27, 48), 'tid': 648606422L, 'price': Decimal('1079.46000000'), 'type': -1, 'amount': Decimal('94.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 27, 50), 'tid': 648606499L, 'price': Decimal('1079.31000000'), 'type': 1, 'amount': Decimal('80.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 27, 50), 'tid': 648606478L, 'price': Decimal('1079.31000000'), 'type': -1, 'amount': Decimal('6.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 27, 50), 'tid': 648606476L, 'price': Decimal('1079.31000000'), 'type': -1, 'amount': Decimal('34.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 27, 50), 'tid': 648606474L, 'price': Decimal('1079.55000000'), 'type': -1, 'amount': Decimal('8.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 27, 55), 'tid': 648606666L, 'price': Decimal('1079.31000000'), 'type': 1, 'amount': Decimal('44.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 27, 55), 'tid': 648606650L, 'price': Decimal('1079.17000000'), 'type': 1, 'amount': Decimal('8.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 27, 55), 'tid': 648606648L, 'price': Decimal('1079.17000000'), 'type': 1, 'amount': Decimal('8.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 28, 1), 'tid': 648606820L, 'price': Decimal('1079.03000000'), 'type': -1, 'amount': Decimal('28.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 28, 2), 'tid': 648606825L, 'price': Decimal('1079.03000000'), 'type': 1, 'amount': Decimal('30.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 28, 2), 'tid': 648606836L, 'price': Decimal('1079.02000000'), 'type': -1, 'amount': Decimal('22.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 28, 5), 'tid': 648606945L, 'price': Decimal('1078.58000000'), 'type': -1, 'amount': Decimal('2.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 28, 5), 'tid': 648606943L, 'price': Decimal('1078.61000000'), 'type': -1, 'amount': Decimal('2.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 28, 5), 'tid': 648606941L, 'price': Decimal('1078.63000000'), 'type': -1, 'amount': Decimal('2.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 28, 5), 'tid': 648606939L, 'price': Decimal('1078.88000000'), 'type': -1, 'amount': Decimal('2.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 28, 5), 'tid': 648606926L, 'price': Decimal('1078.88000000'), 'type': -1, 'amount': Decimal('428.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 28, 6), 'tid': 648606984L, 'price': Decimal('1078.58000000'), 'type': 1, 'amount': Decimal('2.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 28, 6), 'tid': 648606982L, 'price': Decimal('1078.05000000'), 'type': -1, 'amount': Decimal('10.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 28, 6), 'tid': 648606971L, 'price': Decimal('1078.58000000'), 'type': 1, 'amount': Decimal('2.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 28, 6), 'tid': 648606957L, 'price': Decimal('1078.05000000'), 'type': -1, 'amount': Decimal('74.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 28, 6), 'tid': 648606955L, 'price': Decimal('1078.15000000'), 'type': -1, 'amount': Decimal('6.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 28, 6), 'tid': 648606953L, 'price': Decimal('1078.15000000'), 'type': -1, 'amount': Decimal('14.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 28, 6), 'tid': 648606951L, 'price': Decimal('1078.42000000'), 'type': -1, 'amount': Decimal('16.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 28, 7), 'tid': 648606992L, 'price': Decimal('1078.05000000'), 'type': -1, 'amount': Decimal('2.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 28, 7), 'tid': 648606995L, 'price': Decimal('1078.58000000'), 'type': 1, 'amount': Decimal('2.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 28, 7), 'tid': 648607023L, 'price': Decimal('1078.06000000'), 'type': -1, 'amount': Decimal('4.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 28, 8), 'tid': 648607047L, 'price': Decimal('1078.86000000'), 'type': 1, 'amount': Decimal('2.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 28, 10), 'tid': 648607113L, 'price': Decimal('1078.06000000'), 'type': -1, 'amount': Decimal('2.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 28, 10), 'tid': 648607115L, 'price': Decimal('1078.03000000'), 'type': -1, 'amount': Decimal('148.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 28, 12), 'tid': 648607192L, 'price': Decimal('1079.00000000'), 'type': -1, 'amount': Decimal('10.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 28, 13), 'tid': 648607218L, 'price': Decimal('1078.99000000'), 'type': 1, 'amount': Decimal('98.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 28, 13), 'tid': 648607220L, 'price': Decimal('1079.00000000'), 'type': 1, 'amount': Decimal('42.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 28, 13), 'tid': 648607222L, 'price': Decimal('1079.03000000'), 'type': 1, 'amount': Decimal('342.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 28, 13), 'tid': 648607224L, 'price': Decimal('1079.16000000'), 'type': 1, 'amount': Decimal('512.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 28, 14), 'tid': 648607250L, 'price': Decimal('1078.98000000'), 'type': 1, 'amount': Decimal('44.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 28, 14), 'tid': 648607252L, 'price': Decimal('1078.98000000'), 'type': 1, 'amount': Decimal('12.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 28, 14), 'tid': 648607254L, 'price': Decimal('1079.00000000'), 'type': 1, 'amount': Decimal('106.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 28, 14), 'tid': 648607256L, 'price': Decimal('1079.16000000'), 'type': 1, 'amount': Decimal('40.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 28, 20), 'tid': 648607431L, 'price': Decimal('1079.16000000'), 'type': 1, 'amount': Decimal('28.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 28, 20), 'tid': 648607429L, 'price': Decimal('1079.01000000'), 'type': 1, 'amount': Decimal('2.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 28, 20), 'tid': 648607427L, 'price': Decimal('1079.01000000'), 'type': 1, 'amount': Decimal('2.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 28, 23), 'tid': 648607518L, 'price': Decimal('1079.16000000'), 'type': 1, 'amount': Decimal('8.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 28, 24), 'tid': 648607544L, 'price': Decimal('1079.16000000'), 'type': 1, 'amount': Decimal('344.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 28, 25), 'tid': 648607593L, 'price': Decimal('1078.79000000'), 'type': -1, 'amount': Decimal('6.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 28, 26), 'tid': 648607631L, 'price': Decimal('1079.16000000'), 'type': 1, 'amount': Decimal('430.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 28, 26), 'tid': 648607623L, 'price': Decimal('1079.16000000'), 'type': 1, 'amount': Decimal('18.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 28, 26), 'tid': 648607621L, 'price': Decimal('1078.79000000'), 'type': 1, 'amount': Decimal('14.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 28, 29), 'tid': 648607695L, 'price': Decimal('1079.16000000'), 'type': 1, 'amount': Decimal('776.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 28, 32), 'tid': 648607803L, 'price': Decimal('1079.16000000'), 'type': 1, 'amount': Decimal('2.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 28, 32), 'tid': 648607805L, 'price': Decimal('1079.16000000'), 'type': 1, 'amount': Decimal('10.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 28, 36), 'tid': 648607905L, 'price': Decimal('1079.16000000'), 'type': 1, 'amount': Decimal('2.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 28, 37), 'tid': 648607940L, 'price': Decimal('1079.31000000'), 'type': 1, 'amount': Decimal('2.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 28, 42), 'tid': 648608110L, 'price': Decimal('1079.46000000'), 'type': -1, 'amount': Decimal('12.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 28, 46), 'tid': 648608211L, 'price': Decimal('1079.88000000'), 'type': -1, 'amount': Decimal('12.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 28, 46), 'tid': 648608213L, 'price': Decimal('1079.88000000'), 'type': -1, 'amount': Decimal('6.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 28, 57), 'tid': 648608534L, 'price': Decimal('1080.29000000'), 'type': 1, 'amount': Decimal('14.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 28, 57), 'tid': 648608536L, 'price': Decimal('1080.30000000'), 'type': 1, 'amount': Decimal('2.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 29, 2), 'tid': 648608683L, 'price': Decimal('1080.59000000'), 'type': 1, 'amount': Decimal('40.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 29, 3), 'tid': 648608733L, 'price': Decimal('1080.59000000'), 'type': 1, 'amount': Decimal('360.00000000')}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 21, 13, 29, 7), 'tid': 648608838L, 'price': Decimal('1080.90000000'), 'type': 1, 'amount': Decimal('82.00000000')}]
```

if I didn't use set_index ,it will have an `TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'`

```
if rows:
    df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
    print df.head()
    # TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'
    df = df.set_index("date")
    print df.head()
    resample_data = df.resample("1min", how={"price": "ohlc", "amount": "sum"})
    print resample_data
```

Result :

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 162.1967.10)
        amount                date          price        tid  type
0   2.00000000 2017-03-21 11:15:12  1075.83000000  648370156    -1
1  10.00000000 2017-03-21 11:15:15  1076.00000000  648370241    -1
2  10.00000000 2017-03-21 11:15:17  1075.83000000  648370297    -1
3  10.00000000 2017-03-21 11:15:17  1075.83000000  648370311     1
4   8.00000000 2017-03-21 11:15:19  1076.13000000  648370370     1
                          amount          price        tid  type
date                                                            
2017-03-21 11:15:12   2.00000000  1075.83000000  648370156    -1
2017-03-21 11:15:15  10.00000000  1076.00000000  648370241    -1
2017-03-21 11:15:17  10.00000000  1075.83000000  648370297    -1
2017-03-21 11:15:17  10.00000000  1075.83000000  648370311     1
2017-03-21 11:15:19   8.00000000  1076.13000000  648370370     1
/Users/wyx/bitcoin_workspace/fibo-strategy/ticker.py:45: FutureWarning: how in .resample() is deprecated
the new syntax is .resample(...)..apply(<func>)
  resample_data = df.resample("1min", how={"price": "ohlc", "amount": "sum"})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1580, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 964, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/Users/wyx/bitcoin_workspace/fibo-strategy/ticker.py", line 45, in <module>
    resample_data = df.resample("1min", how={"price": "ohlc", "amount": "sum"})
  File "/Users/wyx/bitcoin_workspace/fibo-strategy/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 4216, in resample
    limit=limit)
  File "/Users/wyx/bitcoin_workspace/fibo-strategy/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tseries/resample.py", line 582, in _maybe_process_deprecations
    r = r.aggregate(how)
  File "/Users/wyx/bitcoin_workspace/fibo-strategy/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tseries/resample.py", line 320, in aggregate
    result, how = self._aggregate(arg, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/wyx/bitcoin_workspace/fibo-strategy/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py", line 549, in _aggregate
    result = _agg(arg, _agg_1dim)
  File "/Users/wyx/bitcoin_workspace/fibo-strategy/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py", line 500, in _agg
    result[fname] = func(fname, agg_how)
  File "/Users/wyx/bitcoin_workspace/fibo-strategy/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py", line 483, in _agg_1dim
    return colg.aggregate(how, _level=(_level or 0) + 1)
  File "/Users/wyx/bitcoin_workspace/fibo-strategy/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 2652, in aggregate
    return getattr(self, func_or_funcs)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/wyx/bitcoin_workspace/fibo-strategy/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 1128, in ohlc
    lambda x: x._cython_agg_general('ohlc'))
  File "/Users/wyx/bitcoin_workspace/fibo-strategy/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 3103, in _apply_to_column_groupbys
    return func(self)
  File "/Users/wyx/bitcoin_workspace/fibo-strategy/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 1128, in <lambda>
    lambda x: x._cython_agg_general('ohlc'))
  File "/Users/wyx/bitcoin_workspace/fibo-strategy/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 808, in _cython_agg_general
    raise DataError('No numeric types to aggregate')
pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am a rookie for pandas.

1. How solve the error?
2. And if I want to use the last close price to fill the NaN of next
   min ohlc. How to do that?

Comment: You are going to change the question after it was answered?

Comment: I try set_index before you answer. After I edited another Error ,I see your answer.Sorry, @Stephen Rauch

Comment: You can note that my answer does not have the same problem.  So, you need to post data that allows others to replicate your problem.  If you note the way I posted data, this is one way to make sure the results are reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set an index using your dates.

**Code:**

```
from io import StringIO 
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(
    u"""amount    date          price        tid  type
   6.00000000 2017-03-21t10:46:32  1059.26000000  648313975    -1
   4.00000000 2017-03-21t10:46:37  1059.42000000  648314094    -1
   2.00000000 2017-03-21t10:46:37  1059.42000000  648314096    -1
   2.00000000 2017-03-21t10:46:41  1059.26000000  648314176    -1
  32.00000000 2017-03-21t10:46:41  1059.26000000  648314189    -1
"""), sep='\s+', parse_dates='date'.split())
print(df)

resample_data = df.set_index('date').resample(
    "1min", how={"price": "ohlc", "amount": "sum"})

print(resample_data)
```

**Results:**

```
   amount                date    price        tid  type
0     6.0 2017-03-21 10:46:32  1059.26  648313975    -1
1     4.0 2017-03-21 10:46:37  1059.42  648314094    -1
2     2.0 2017-03-21 10:46:37  1059.42  648314096    -1
3     2.0 2017-03-21 10:46:41  1059.26  648314176    -1
4    32.0 2017-03-21 10:46:41  1059.26  648314189    -1

                       price                            amount
                        open     high      low    close amount
date                                                          
2017-03-21 10:46:00  1059.26  1059.42  1059.26  1059.26   46.0
```

Comment: When I use set_index  I got another error :`pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate`, I have update my question , I want to cry......@Stephen Rauch